# Delete certain line in text file using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file . I want to delete line 4 and line 5 only.

**Before**

```
Line1  
Line2  
Line3  
Line4 (need to delete)  
Line5 (need to delete)  
Line6
```

**After**

```
Line1  
Line2  
Line3  
Line6
```

Comment: How do you select lines 4 and 5? By content or by position?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :CopyLines < input.txt > output.txt
move /Y output.txt input.txt
goto :EOF


:CopyLines

rem Copy lines 1, 2 and 3
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   echo(!line!
)

rem Omit lines 4 and 5
for /L %%i in (4,1,5) do set /P "line="

rem Copy the rest
findstr "^"

exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code which would do exactly what you require :

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
if exist neww.txt (del /s /q neww.txt) 

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (onee.txt) do (
set /a count+=1

if !count! EQU 4 (
echo do nothing
)else if !count! EQU 5 (
echo do nothing
)else (
echo %%a>>neww.txt
)
)

move /y neww.txt onee.txt
```